# instagram API get real-time updates for #hashtags only from authenticated user accounts

Tags: real-time, instagram, updates, instagram-api

I have registered my app with instagram API. I have subscribed to hashtag(say, #fun) real-time updates. But I want instagram to notify me only when the users authenticated with my app tags the photo with hashtag(say, #fun). The problem is, if I subscribe to most common words, I am getting too many POST request(any one who tags with #fun) from IG which is the scalable issue. Is there any good approach to solve this problem.??

Answer (score 0):

I've done this the long way. I get all the updates from registered uses and then discard the media items that don't have the correct tags in the object. It's the long way of doing it... but it works.